Limit range from start to end in Joi validation
Add Joi validation in nodeJs to limit endDate to be no more than 3 years after startDate.
Example :
startDate 2024-03-29 ,
max endDate should be: 2027-03-29.
I tried:
const maxEndDate = Joi.ref('startDate', {
  adjust: startDate => startDate.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (365 * 3)
});

const validate =
  query: {
    endDate: Joi.date().format(DATE_FORMAT).utc().min(Joi.ref('startDate')).max(maxEndDate).raw().required(),
  }

and
const maxEndDate = Joi.ref('startDate', { adjust: ['+3 years'] })


but looks like it doesn't add 3 years, it only takes startDate as ref and gives error:
"message": "\"endDate\" must be less than or equal to \"Fri Mar 29 2024 03:00:00 GMT+0300\"


There is a corrections needed.

When defining the validation schema, you should use Joi.object() to wrap the query object.

You can try:
const maxEndDate = Joi.ref('startDate', {
  adjust: startDate => startDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 3) 
});

Instead of :
const maxEndDate = Joi.ref('startDate', {
  adjust: startDate => startDate.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (365 * 3)
});

And
const validate = Joi.object({
  query: Joi.object({
    startDate: Joi.date().format(DATE_FORMAT).utc().required(),
    endDate: Joi.date().format(DATE_FORMAT).utc().min(Joi.ref('startDate')).max(maxEndDate).required(),
  })
});

Instead of:
const validate =
      query: {
        endDate: 
Joi.date().format(DATE_FORMAT).utc().min(Joi.ref('startDate')).max(maxEndDate).raw().required(),
      }


TypeError: Joi.ref(...).iso is not a function

can you give me full code?

Remove .iso() and it should work fine.

Tried already,
startDate: Joi.date().format(DATE_FORMAT).utc().raw().required(),
endDate: Joi.date().format(DATE_FORMAT).utc().min(Joi.ref('startDate')).max(maxEndDate).required(),
AND
const maxEndDate = Joi.ref('startDate', {
adjust: startDate => startDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 3)
})
same..

Same means? .iso() is not a function or date not added 3 years? Have you add this line const Joi = require('joi').extend(require('@joi/date')); begining of your code?

date not added 3 years.
I did add import, it is a big file working long time with JOI, can not attach, need only to change enddate condition

Condition depend on scenario, so without knowing proper scenario, solution is not possible.

Scenario is: getting a startDate and EndDate return calendar data for this range.  Limitations: endDate must be no more than 3 years than startDate and not smaller than startDate.

See testcase here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mhlllj?file=index.js. Write node index.js in the terminal. Change the data endDate to see the result.
